# Difference between Uber API credits and personal referral code?

Tags: uber-api

I'm making an iOS mapping app, with an option to open the specified route (starting point and destination) in the Uber app. I'm passing in my client ID, and it works fine. For example, I call openURL with this string:

uber://?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&link_text=Watch%20progress%20in%20my%20app&partner_deeplink=SOMEDEEPLINK%3A%2F%2F&&pickup[latitude]=123.456&pickup[longitude]=123.456&pickup[nickname]=PICKUP&pickup[formatted_address]=123%20Elm%20St&dropoff[latitude]=123.456&dropoff[longitude]=123.456&dropoff[nickname]=DROPOFF&dropoff[formatted_address]=456%20Elm%20St

(This sample URL includes some obviously fake data, for the sake of simplicity.)

For those users who don't have Uber installed, how can I maximize the earnings (from those who sign up)? It sounds like Uber will automatically credit me $5.00 if the user signs up. But if I give the user my personal invite code, then I earn a free ride (up to $20).

Assuming I'd rather earn free rides instead of $5 credits, can I do this? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Uber legal terms, specifically the parts around promo codes: https://www.uber.com/legal/terms/us/  "(ii) may not be duplicated, sold or transferred in any manner, or made available to the general public"

In general this promo code is for personal use vs a business use available to the general public. So the affiliate payments would be applicable for your app- not using your personal promo code.

Then in general the promo code is for rides up to $20 and auto-applies to your next ride, even if it is only a $5 ride. The promo code also expires after 3 months. So in addition to it being against terms, just personally I'd rather have $5 I can use on anything. Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Kyle